# DropdownList in ASP.NET MVC 5 TemplateEditor not binding and triggers validation error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, html.dropdownlistfor

I have this code in an "EditorTemplates" View in ASP.NET MVC,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State, new SelectList(Model.States), "-- Please Select --")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

This is showing the dropdown and I am able to select a "State". But as soon as the focus changes to another box. The validation error shows up.

[image]

Why is the dropdown not assigning the value to model.state ?

Again this is not the "MainView". The MainView call this "Template" using the following code.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CustomerAddress)
```

Please advise.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `ModelState` (which is server side) - you are getting a client side validation error. What are the `value` attributes of the options you are generating (clearly they are not 2 characters)

Comment: public List<string> States { get; }

        public AddressViewModel()
        {
            States = new List<string>();
            States.Add("CA");
            States.Add("NV");
            States.Add("AZ");
        }

Comment: It is a simple list of strings with 2 characters length.

Comment: And what validation attributes are applied to `State`

Comment: [Required]
        [StringLength(2, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "State")]
        public string State { get; set; }

Comment: Why are you adding the `[StringLength]` attribute? - its not necessary at all

Comment: Yes - That's the issue. I removed that attribute. It was there when this box was a simple text box. I changed it to dropdown. All is working fine now after removing that [stringlength] attribute. Once again. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

With help from 'Stephen Muecke' I was able to find that the [StringLength] attribute was causing the issue. Since the value is coming in from a DropDown list I really don't need that attribute anymore. After removing it the selected value is coming in correctly.